# RecyclerView animates items all at once instead of one by one

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

## My Problem

I've been trying to get my Recycler View's items to animate as I scroll down. These items are loaded from a local XML and passed through my custom adapter.

[I'm using this library for my adapter animation](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)

I noticed that no matter what I tried, the items would just not animate at all, or they would animate all at once (every item would slide in on screen at the same time).

## What I've Tried So Far

Utilizing the library I mentioned, I tried animating items in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

### > `IndexFragment.java` snippet

```
//Create an adapter
SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(songs, getContext());
//Set adapter
AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
alphaAdapter.setFirstOnly(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

This one failed somehow. I also tried the `setItemAnimator` method which also failed.

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());
```

## Layout Structure

So I assume it has something to do with my `RecyclerView` being inside of two `NestedScrollView`'s.

Another person seemed to be having [a similar issue](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/issues/113)

Below are some portions of my layout files

---

#### `activity_main.xml`

```
....
<!-- Fragment Container -->
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
....
```

This is where I put my fragments

#### `index_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is pretty much my Recyclerview and its parent Nested Scrollview.

#### `item_song.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">
        
        <!--I have two text views in here. Removed them just for this snippet -->
        
</LinearLayout>

    <!-- This displays a background on each item when I press them AKA touch effects -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the structure of each item in the Recyclerview. I inflate this layout for each item. Pretty straightforward.

---

Any ideas as to what I could do to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much testing, I finally came up with a solution that worked.

1. Change the fragment container in `activity_main.xml` from `NestedScrollView` to **`RelativeLayout`** or perhaps `LinearLayout`.
2. Remove the parent `NestedScrollView` and keep only the `RecyclerView` in `index_fragment.xml`.
3. Animations now work at last. Yay!

Apparently, **it is a bad idea to put your RecyclerView inside of a NestedScrollView.**

I read somewhere that because of having to load the proper height of its child layout, the `NestedScrollView` has to wait for it to completely load, in order to know the total height of the `RecyclerView`. However, I'm not totally sure if that's the reason, so feel free to correct me.

Hope this helps someone!